# How to list the names of all the blocks of a .dwg file in AutoCAD CORE console?

Tags: autocad, autocad-plugin, dwg

i will get custom block in a .dwg file from a list of blocks which I will parse programmatically in Java.

Comment: Have you tried anything? Stack Overflow will not write your program for you.

Comment: i would suppose the answer to be similar to a one line command... example "LISTALLBLOCK" or "GETALLBLOCKNAME"... thanks for pointing out that StackOverflow does not help me code though...

Comment: For a better chance of having your question answered, at least add to your question something like `I looked at the documentation [link to documentation here] and couldn't find a way to do this.`

Comment: Java? No, unless you call an AutoCAD instance via COM but I don't think the core console works with COM and I never intend to find out. C# - yes, Lisp - yes. but @Maxence's answer is the easiest one in this case.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the command INSERT with the option ?

```
cd C:\Program Files\Autodesk\AutoCAD 2016
accoreconsole.exe /i "Sample\Database Connectivity\Floor Plan Sample.dwg"
Command: _INSERT
Enter block name or [?]: ?

Enter block(s) to list <*>:

Defined blocks.
  "CHAIR7"
  "COMPUTER"
  "DESK2"
  "DESK3"
  "DOOR"
  "DR-36"
  "DR-69P"
  "DR-72P"
  "FC15X27A"
  "FC42X18D"
  "FNPHONE"
  "IBMAT"
  "KEYBOARD"
  "NCL-HL"
  "RECTANG"
  "RMNUM"
  "SOFA2"

User     Unnamed
Blocks   Blocks
   17        0
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not familiar with `Core Console` but for listing all block in a `DWG` file, you need to use `LISP`s. Something like `axBlock` from [jtbworld](http://www.jtbworld.com/lisp/axblock.htm) . You may also mock around with LISP code and call it via a `SCRIPT`.

---

Edit:

Copy and paste following code in `Notepad` and save it as `axBlock.lsp` in the root fo your `C` drive (for instance):

```
(defun c:axblocks (/ b bn tl)
  (vlax-for b (vla-get-blocks
                (vla-get-ActiveDocument (vlax-get-acad-object))
              )
    (if (= (vla-get-islayout b) :vlax-false)
      (setq tl (cons (vla-get-name b) tl))
    )
  )
  (reverse tl)
)
```

I just tweaked jtbworld's code a little bit to make it easier for you.

Now you have your LISP code ready and you only need to load it into AutoCAD. You have couple of options for that:

1. Use APPLOAD command in AutoCAD and browse for `axBlock.lsp` which
   you just created
2. Drag `axBlock.lsp` over your AutoCAD window.
3. Call `axBlock.lsp` via a script file. And scripts are nothing
   really
       but a simple textual file with `*.scr` extension. For that you just
       need this line of code to be in your script file:

   `(load "C:\\axBlock.lsp")`

After doing any of above three methods, as long as you type `axBlock` in AutoCAD and hit `Enter`, you will see the list of existing blocks.

Moreover, if you followed approach no.3 from above list, you can make a shortcut and call `axBlock` within the script file as well i.e. you load and call the function in one hit. If you want to do so, just add `axBlock` in the second line of your script code. Note there an extra `SPACE` after `axBlock`

Comment: AutoCAD does no have much functionality on it's CoreConsole... however can u point me in the right direction on how to run .lsp scripts in a SCRIPT file??

Comment: @user3336544 read my edited answer. I added more description to it.

Comment: I did everything on Number 3 but the console just re-prints each line and quits... this method is the most useful to me but i can't get it to work..

Comment: @user3336544 I need to see some screenshot in order to be able to help you further.

Comment: turns out Visual Lisps does not work on the Core Console..... and the best way would be to call a script that calls a lisp routine on acad.exe... ex: acad.exe C:\<pathing...>\ my_autocad_file.dwg /b call_attout_routine.scr